How to prove the equivalence of two set expressions
Suppose we have following function:
$f: A \mapsto B \ $
with following definitions:
$ \ Y \subseteq B, \ y \in B$
$f^{-1}(Y) = \{ a\in A\mid f(a)\in Y \}$
$f^{-1}(y) = \{ a\in A\mid f(a) = y \}$
How can we prove the following:
$f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(\{y\})$
I know that above equation can be translated to this:
$\{ a\in A\mid f(a)\in \{y\} \} = \{ a\in A\mid f(a) = y \}$
My intuition is that in this specific case, mathematical equivalence (=) behaves the same as the element of ($\in$) operator.
To prove this, one has to show two things:
$\{ a\in A\mid f(a)\in \{y\} \} \subseteq \{ a\in A\mid f(a) = y \}$
$\{ a\in A\mid f(a) = y \} \subseteq \{ a\in A\mid f(a)\in \{y\} \}$
How can I write a mathematically convincing proof that these two statements are indeed the same?

This is the definition of ${y}$. $$b\in{y}\iff b=y.$$You don't need to prove separately the two inclusions. Simply use that if $P(a)\iff Q(a)$ then $${a\in A\mid P(a)}={a\in A\mid Q(a)}.$$

Take an element in one set and show that it must be in the other set as well. And vice versa.

@AnneBauval For beginners I usually suggest to show two inclusions, this is the safest method. What you wrote is obviously (at least for those who are already comfortable with this stuff) correct, but more advanced.

@aslary To hammer the nail, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality#Formal_statement: if $\forall a\quad(a\in X\iff a\in Y)$, then $X=Y$.
